# Is there a way to for Sharepoint Online to access the Adobe PDF meta-data keywords that I have applied on my PDF's?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, pdf, keyword

Is there an app, setting, web-part or other solution so that **SharePoint** can harvest (obtain, discovery, find--whatever is the right terminology) the **Adobe Acrobat Pro** key-word **Meta-Data** that I have dutifully applied to my PDFs?

It appears that Sharepoint Online is not finding the meta-data that I entered via Adobe Acrobat Pro through the properties pane. Is there a Sharepoint online solution that will allow me to exploit the work I've put in?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB there is no way to extract metadata from PDF files. There are apps that provide this functionality. For example, the apps can extract all standard properties plus custom metadata fields from PDF files. See [here](https://www.slimapplications.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ExplorerExtractMetadataPDF.png).

The extracted values can be captured into SharePoint columns and then used for sorting, filtering and searching.

Can you perhaps share or mail an example pdf file? (not containing sensitive information)

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Metadata on (Adobe) PDF files are out of reach for SharePoint itself. There is no such app or tool or web part in SharePoint that can manage this request.

You can see a UserVoice here and vote for it if that’s something you agree with:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/15412686-metadata-integration-into-pdfs